# How to skip a task to be executed in Github Actions under always()

Tags: github-actions, workflow

How to have a block which is always executed, even in failure scenario. But, skipped if a file is not created in workspace in Github Actions (say index.html)

After adding below condition and file not existing in workspace too, task is getting executed.

if: {{always()}} && file_check == 'true'

Comment: The syntax of that condition is not correct. Please include your relevant workflow in your question showing where that `file_check` is populated. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.